# What are the reasons behind the scenes that make self hosted videos not run on mobile

Tags: ios, wordpress, video, self-hosting

With the risk to get some down votes here for not offering concise code here, I try to ask this question here. Googling does not help at all. One finds a bunch of sites advising you to NOT self host videos on your webpage (wether wordpress or static). Ok but that’s not my point. If you have to? (maybe some client asks you to do it)

I tried as an example tons of plugins (video players) for wordpress for a self hosted video which works very fine (with several file options delivered) on all current browsers but it won’t run on mobile, i.g. iPad and others. It is displayed but I cannot play it.

And I cannot get an answer why? Can this be due to the video itself? Some encoding secrets? I tried .mp4 .webm and some others. No success.

Any help, any hint here would be so awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Ok. It is the video in itself not the embedding into the page that creates problems: I found this link very helpful:

https://www.broken-links.com/2010/07/30/encoding-video-for-android/

In “Handbrake” there are also many presets and stuff for iPad etc.

Sorry for not having done sufficient research before!